# Unity Error: Exporting to Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, export

I have the following error, when I export to Android from Unity:

> Error building Player: Win32Exception:
>   ApplicationName='C:/Users/joaog_000/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\tools\aapt.exe',
>   CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M
>   AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I
>   "C:/Users/joaog_000/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-15\android.jar"
>   -F bin/resources.ap_', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'

What can I do?

Comment: Used a quote block and restated the title in the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether **android sdk** is properly installed.
The error says that the **aapt.exe** is missing from the sdk\tools Check and add it to the sdk and then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Things you could do:

1. Have you installed the java and android SDKs? If no, install them.
2. Did you set the location of the Android SDK in Edit/Preferences?
3. Clear the temp folder, restart Unity and try again.
4. Search for the aapt.exe file from other android versions \android-XX\ and copy to the stated \android-15\ in your error.
5. Launch your SDKManager and check for updates.